# Error while trying to build wheel for yarl 1.7.2 python library

Tags: python, package

When trying to build wheel for yarl 1.7.2 in Python, I receive the following error.

### The error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: yarl
  Building wheel for yarl (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for yarl (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [44 lines of output]
      C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-xkaxs9r3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:520: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      **********************
      * Accelerated build *
      **********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\_url.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      running egg_info
      writing yarl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to yarl.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.html'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.so'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.pyd'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying yarl\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_c.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      running build_ext
      building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yarl
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcyarl/_quoting_c.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yarl/_quoting_c.obj
      _quoting_c.c
      yarl/_quoting_c.c(198): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried to install a different version of build tools (2015) and Microsoft c++ build tools (2022) with default install settings but still gave the same error.

Comment: this is the error i'm trying to solve:   error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2 [end of output]

Comment: It's not formatted in a code block. Therefore, it's very hard to read your error.